# getting type error : expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am facing a challenge where I am trying to clean a column in my dataset using the regular expression in python. The column is of object type and when I am using the below code I am getting this error: expected string or bytes-like object

```
import re 
def clean_str(string):
    """
    Tokenization/string cleaning for dataset
    Every dataset is lower cased except
    """
    string = re.sub(r"\n", "", string)    
    string = re.sub(r"\r", "", string) 
    string = re.sub(r"[0-9]", "digit", string)
    string = re.sub(r"\'", "", string)   
    string = re.sub(r"\"", "", string)    
    return string.strip().lower()
X = []
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    X.append(clean_str(df.iloc[i][1])) #0,1,2,3
y = np.array(df["Standardpositionsname"])
```

Comment: Please indent your code correctly. As it stands that code is unreadable.

Comment: Can you read it now?

Comment: Oh gosh no.  It was better the other way.  Is there a line number in the error message?

Comment: Should I share the traceback call? will that help?

Comment: Absolutely.  And always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Think in  `X.append(clean_str(df.iloc[i][1]))` you must convert parameter to string type 
like this

`X.append(clean_str(str(df.iloc[i][1])))`